# SQL Azure and READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT

Tags: performance, azure-sql-database, read-committed-snapshot

I would like to set READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT to ON on my SQL Azure database, but the following code, which works with other versions of SQL Server, is not supported in Azure:

```
ALTER DATABASE [database_name]
SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON
GO
```

First question: Is it still a good idea to set READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT to ON in SQL Azure (or whatever achieves the same result)? My intention is not to lock records when they are just being read, in order to improve performance.

Second question: If it is a good idea, what's the Azure syntax for doing it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From what I can tell based on [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336245.aspx) the setting you are after is on by default and cannot be changed. More details about the Isolation Levels themselves can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189050.aspx).