# What do I expect from changing default transaction isolation level from READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT to READ_COMMITTED?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, isolation-level, transaction-isolation

In SQL Server the default isolation level is `READ_COMMITTED` but in SQL Azure the default level is `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT`.

Suppose I change the default level in my SQL Azure server to `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` (using `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL`) so that it behaves like SQL Server.

What negative consequences should I expect?

Comment: The short answer is that you can't do this in SQL Azure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036986/sql-azure-and-read-committed-snapshot

Comment: @twoleggedhorse: This can't be done per database, but it can be done per connection, can't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application logic may break. Really, it depends a lot on what you're doing. Overall, some pointers:

- True SNAPSHOT has a lot less 'surprises' than RCSI. As the 'snapshot' rows version is clearly defined in the true  SNAPSHOT as the moment the transaction started, it does not suffer from RCSI issues of seeing different row versions inside the same transaction (which leads to very subtle and difficult to understand issues)
- You will get update conflicts instead of deadlocks, but one *exactly* 'instead-of'. There are some differences, and definetely the app may not expect the new error code 3960.

I would recommend going over [Implementing Snapshot or Read Committed Snapshot Isolation in SQL Server: A Guide](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/).

Comment: The point is that you cannot change this setting in SQL Azure

Comment: @twoleggedhorse: actually you can. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/handling-transactions-in-sql-azure.aspx

Comment: @twoleggedhorse: Actually, you're right. I've read the OP (and answered such...) as 'change from RCSI to SNAPSHOT', which is possible. Change from RCSI to 'READ COMMITTED' is not possible in Azure.

Comment: +1 It's not often someone admits that I'm right - I'm going to enjoy this :)